# Highcharts DataGrouping with Null values

Tags: highcharts

Having an issue where we're trying to show a gap in data when nulls are present in the data set with dataGrouping enabled on the Highstock chart.

If the data set is small, like in the images below, leaving dataGrouping disabled isn't an issue.

The problem comes in when we have a very large data set, 2 days worth of data x 4 series = 690,000+ data points; the data takes forever to load.

If we leave dataGrouping enabled, then the gap in the data disappears.

Is it possible to get keep dataGrouping enabled but also show the gap for nulls?

[image: DataGrouping Disabled]
[image: DataGrouping Enabled]

Comment: Hi @BBousman, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ge1brx2/ the chart works correctly.

Comment: I tried creating one on JSFiddle using the CSVUrl which is how we have it setup but it's not letting me in Chrome due to the csv being on another website. If I manually put the data in, it seems to work fine but it's not really a 1:1 comparison.

Comment: @ppotaczek I uploaded a sample Visual Studio project that shows what we're seeing: [link](https://filebin.net/jqg7ukmsrl7cyo3p/HighstockTest.zip?t=v2u3ayf8)

Comment: The data source should not have any affect. I am unable to run your project, so could you try reproduce the problem in jsfiddle once again?

Comment: @ppotaczek okay, I set up a JSFiddle and managed to get it to work; if you change the dataGrouping variable to true, you'll see what I'm seeing:
https://jsfiddle.net/BBousman/p472nguk/

Comment: Thank you for the example, I have found the problem and added solution as an answer.

Comment: Thank you sir! That did the trick! I'm guessing it thought they were nulls because all the previous values have quotes around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by your data - all of the null values are strings:

```
200: (2) [1569876448000, "null"]
201: (2) [1569876449000, "null"]
202: (2) [1569876450000, "null"]
203: (2) [1569876451000, "null"]
204: (2) [1569876452000, "null"]
205: (2) [1569876453000, "null"]
206: (2) [1569876454000, "null"]
207: (2) [1569876455000, "null"]
208: (2) [1569876456000, "null"]
209: (2) [1569876457000, "null"]
210: (2) [1569876458000, "null"]
211: (2) [1569876459000, "null"]
```

As a solution you should change the format or parse the data in the `complete` function:

```
data: {
    csvURL: '...',
    complete: function(options) {
        options.series.forEach(function(s) {
            s.data.forEach(function(p) {
                if (p[1] === 'null') {
                    p[1] = null;
                }
            });
        });
    },
    enablePolling: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c0xd5j62/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Answer (score 0):

Try using broken-axis module, see http://jsfiddle.net/awrydgs7/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can this be used alongside the CSVUrl property? We're loading all our data from a CSV file currently.

Comment: Also, we're using HighStock and not HighCharts